# links don't work on iPad

Tags: ipad, hyperlink

At the bottom of [my page](http://tinyurl.com/qjjgtqp), there are four big square link tabs (called "individual", "group", "child" and "family"). Those tabs work fine on my desktop computer, but for some reason they don't work on iPad.

The strange thing is that when touching them on iPad, the hover effect functions but then nothing happens. What is going on with these links?

Here's the HTML of one of the four tabs:

```
<a href="https://www.mud-kings.com/events/individual/" id="a_price_li1">
    <img src="http://www.mud-kings.com/wp-content/themes/mudkings/images/register_individual.png" id="register_individual" class="register_tab" style="display: block;">
    <img src="http://www.mud-kings.com/wp-content/themes/mudkings/images/register_individual2.png" id="register_individual2" class="register_tab" style="display: none;">
</a>
```

With the following jQuery code attached to it:

```
jQuery('#a_price_li1').hover(
        function () {   jQuery('#register_individual').css('display','none');   jQuery('#register_individual2').css('display','block'); },
        function () {   jQuery('#register_individual').css('display','block');  jQuery('#register_individual2').css('display','none');  }   
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@drake035, I managed to find some similar questions (with answers) asked by other people with more or less the same problem. My suggestion would be take a look and see if the information provided in there solves your problem (since I have some doubts I will ask you bellow).

[iPad hover/click issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978288/ipad-hover-click-issue)

[hover effect on a tablet (i.e. iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114608/hover-effect-on-a-tablet-i-e-ipad)

In order to be aware of the current situation, what kind of knowledge in web programming do you have?
What makes you think there is the problem only?

Greetings, Martin